# Is there a way to save an incremented variable after a script finishes

Tags: lua, increment

I am trying to make a script that is going to be used to test our website, part of this includes the incrementation of a variable which needs to then be saved so when the script is run again, that variable will be one greater then the last time the script was run. I know how to increment a variable, its just I have no clue how to save that variable so it wont be reset to its original value at the start of the next run. Also this is in LUA programming language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set a cookie, or open a session and set a session variable.

http://keplerproject.github.io/cgilua/libraries.html

More info: [nginx lua redis cookie not setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20528680/nginx-lua-redis-cookie-not-setting)

Comment: Do you know how to set a cookie in lua? I just took a look and there aren't many examples. But yes, that would make sense if i can figure it out.

Comment: I don't actually, but added a link that might help.

Comment: Be sure you are looking for ways to set a cookie in nginx and not Lua.